# How to use Tesseract as Nuget package in C++ Console Application Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nuget, ocr, tesseract

My goal is to extract numbers and text from an input image using Tesseract in C++ with Nuget package in VStudio 2022.

I downloaded tesseract 5.2.0 (right click on project -> Manage Nuget packages -> Browse) as Nuget package  5.2.0

[image]

and however when i include tesseract as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>


int main() {
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI* api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    if (api->Init(nullptr, "eng")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize Tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Open an image 
    Pix* image = pixRead("D:/tools/img.png");
    api->SetImage(image);

    // Perform OCR
    char* outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
    std::cout << "OCR Output:\n" << outText << std::endl;

    // Release resources
    api->End();
    delete[] outText;
    pixDestroy(&image);

    return 0;
}
```

it gives me these errors.

[image]

I also read [THIS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TesseractOCR/) and installed runtime 64 but didn work.

Does anyone know the way to use tesseract with C++ as Nuget package or any work around.

Comment: You can take a look at the answer I posted, Both of the packages you mentioned doesn't support native/C++. I give an example package that support native/C++. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Bowman Zhu-MSFT for your answer. It gave me a direction.
After thorough search I am able to find a solution to use tesseract with C++. There is a complete official tesseract [documentation](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Compiling.html). However I didn't go with built solution because it takes longer and and bit more complicated for me. As per Bowman suggestion I tried with [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/README.md#quick-start-windows). Following the steps from the [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/README.md#quick-start-windows)  I installed vckg on windows. For this step :

```
.\vcpkg\vcpkg install [packages to install] --triplet=x64-windows
```

I replaced with this to install tesseract on windows for x64 version

```
.\vcpkg\vcpkg install tesseract:x64-windows-static
```

and finally i run this

```
.\vcpkg\vcpkg integrate install
```

Then I open a new console application with C++ in Visual studio 2022. Now it have to include the packages, includes and lib folders and to do so, i did following steps:

- First go the folder where you have installed the vckpg. It must be having many sub folders.
- Copy the path of the **include** directory inside the vckpg folder. Go to the project in Visual Studio and right click on the project in solution explorer window and choose **properties** option and add the path of the include folder to the **C/C++ -> General -> **Additional Include Directories****
  [image]
- Copy the path of the **lib** directory inside the vckpg folder. Go to the project in Visual Studio and right click on the project in solution explorer window and choose **properties** option and add the path of the include folder to the **Linker -> General -> **Additional Library Directories****
  [image]

then I build and run the same piece of code as i mentioned in my question and everything worked well. Those errors were not there anymore.

However i met with another error from tesseract:

[image]

To get ride of this I have followed the following steps:

- I went to the official [tessdoc](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/Data-Files.md)
- Then I downloaded single "eng" file and saved it on my PC, the eng file i have downloaded from [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best/blob/main/eng.traineddata)
- I have saved the eng file like following subfolder structure **C:\tools\TesseractData\tessdata**. The eng file is inside tessdata folder.
- Then on my PC I added environment variable **TESSDATA_PREFIX** with value as the path **C:\tools\TesseractData\tessdata** of the eng file.
- Finally I restarted my PC and build the project again and run it and tesseract start detecting text and digits like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the package you were using does not supoort the native/C++ code, you can take a look at the package Tesseract page in the NuGet gallery here:

[Tesseract](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tesseract)

For the package that supports native/C++, this is a sample:

[Microsoft.Web.WebView2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2#supportedframeworks-body-tab)

You can download them and take a look at all of them, the first package you were trying to use is a classic NuGet package for the .Net environment(which Nuget Packages ordinarily do.).

As you see, the content of the Tesseract package doesn't contain a .h file in it. That is why you are unable to refer to it in your C++ project.

From the NuGet Gallery, we can also get this information:

**Tesseract:**

[image]

**Microsoft.Web.WebView2**

[image]

Comment: then what is the alternative to use Tesseract for C++ ?

Comment: @KFK Basically, this is a sample: [Sample of using C++ API](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/APIExample.html). And for you to understand it more easily, you should use the vcpkg instead of nupkg: [Document of vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg) By the way, I think you need this website for your C++ projects developing: [VCPKG IO](https://vcpkg.io/) It is similar to nuget gallery website for nuget package. You search whether there are made packages you need which is public.

Comment: @KFK There is exactly a C++ package that exists: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekQC4.png By the way, if my answer is able to answer your original question, could you please [mark it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to end this question? This will be helpful to others who meet a similar issue and seeking for the answer. :)