# Use nuget of vs2022 to install opencv, but an error occurs

Tags: opencv, nuget, visual-studio-2022

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to use opencv with vs2022 for the first time.In vs2022, I created a new empty project and installed opencv using nuget. Next, I created a source file named main.cpp and wrote the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Mat image = imread("112.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
    if (image.empty()) {
        cout << "could not find" << endl;
    }
    imshow("Image", image);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the project I get the following error：

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project5, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::fastFree(void *)" (?fastFree@cv@@YAXPEAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QEAA@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(class cv::Mat const &)" (??0_InputArray@cv@@QEAA@AEBVMat@1@@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl
```

I tried for a long time but couldn't find the reason, because as far as the information I looked up, no one had this error. After they installed opencv using nuget, they could use it normally.

I tried uninstalling opencv and reinstalling but to no avail

Comment: Exactly which NuGet package and version did you install?

Comment: The detail: <package id="OpenCV" version="2.4.11" targetFramework="native" />

Comment: That package hasn't been updated since 2017... I looked at the inner `*.autopkg` file and it only has `PlatformToolset` values up-to VS2015 (and maybe VS2017?) - so I don't think it's compatible with VS2022 at all...

Comment: Yeah, see the `OpenCV.targets` file inside the `nupkg` is where the Linker Dependencies are added, and it if you don't have `$(PlatformToolset) = 140` then it won't work.

Comment: Why are you installing an 8.5 year old release of OpenCV?

Comment: @ILOT The package is published by a person, not official, and it stopped updating for a long time. I found the real opencv project, you can take a look of my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you are using is a very old version package upload by personal, even it is support native code.

Nuget Package is mainly a package for .net environment projects.

I notice the really opencv project is here:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv

And it still updates yesterday.

For your C++ project, you could search the C++ packages and install packages via here:

[VCPKG IO](https://vcpkg.io/en/packages)

This is the official document of it:

[Open CV Documents](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/index.html)

And this is the examples:

[Examples of OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/examples.html)

I think this sample has a part of code which is similar to what you are doing:

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dbc/samples_2cpp_2tutorial_code_2HighGUI_2AddingImagesTrackbar_8cpp-example.html

By the way, you can take a look of this answer, he can success using another C++ library via my direction and he shared the detailed steps:

[How to use Tesseract C++ package in project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77479279/6261890)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With your help I have solved this problem

Comment: @ILOT Hi, since my answer works for you, could you please [mark it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to end this question? this will be helpful to others who encountered the issue and seeking for the answer. :)